# Do all digital potentiometers have discrete resistance options?

Tags: resistors, potentiometer, digital-potentiometer

I'm looking at the [MCP4017](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22147a.pdf) and some others, but they all seem to have discrete resistance options. The MCP4017 offers 5k, 10k, 50k and 100k. Are there digipots out there that offer a continuous spectrum to 100k or 200k? It seems very limited if there's only half a dozen of choices.

Thanks

Comment: Digital pots are, well, *digital*.  So of course it will ultimately operate at one of the 2^N discrete states.  How do you imagine a digital pot NOT having discrete outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MCP4017 is a 7 bit digital pot. That means it has 127 steps between the low end and the high end of the pot resistance. The 5k, 10k, 50k and 100k options refers to the total resistance between the low and high ends.

So if you get the 100k pot, it provides 100,000Ω / 127 Steps = ~787Ω per step (linear pots).

This is how all digital pots work, accounting for resistance and resolution of course.

Standard parts are only going to have standard values, like analog pots, but most companies will make custom ranged parts if you pay them enough.

**Of course, a quick look on Digikey shows digital pots available in various resistance ranges from 1kΩ to 1MΩ. As an arbitrary value, they have 16.5k pots like the DS3930E or a 18.5k ISL22102IV20Z.**

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a need for a particular value?

Normally it is better to use a Digipot in potentiometer mode (using all three pins) than in rheostat mode (just two pins as a variable resistor).

The potentiometer mode will be more accurate and suffer less from variations with temperature.

When using potentiometer mode in most circuits the actual value is relatively unimportant as it is being used ratiometrically.

One reason that high value digipots have limited application is that they have very high parasitic capacitances and the time constants associated with, for example a 1 megohm digipot would mean that they would not work properly above a few kilohertz. The large capacitance exists because there is a MOSFET for every selectable tap (i.e. a 256 tap pot has the capacitance of 256 MOSFETS attached to the resistor chain).

If you look at figure 16 in [Digipot Data sheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5253_5254.pdf) you will see that above 10kHz the response is deteriorating for the 100K ohm version but the 1K version shown in fig13 is good for 1-2MHz.

So the best way to use a Digipot is as a potentiometer and use as low a value as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Being digital, they are sampled, so because there is some finite resolution they will all have discrete values. However, there's a limit to how useful higher resolutions are - even analog potentiometers used in a digital circuit also get sampled, and in reality if your required resolution matters that much you're probably not designing the circuit correctly.

Comment: I think you misuse the word 'sampled' a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you visualze a digital pot as a conventional pot with a stepping motor coupled to its shaft, then it's easy to see that resistance values which fall between the stepper's resting points cant be accessed.